# Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 Column taking up full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just upgraded one of my electron apps to Bootstrap's new Alpha 6 for Bootstrap 4. They made lots of adjustments to the grid system and flexbox and in turn that has given me some wonky bugs in my electron app.
Currently I have a sidebar and a main area.

[image: Imgur]

and the sidebar is taking up the whole width of the screen, even though I have it defined as .col-4 .col-xl-3,

[image: Imgur]

And it is shoving everything to the right of it down below. How can I prevent this behavior from happening?

Edit: More code, the previous issue is fixed but with @haxxtron's answer, there is now no padding on the left hand side.

```
    <div class ="row">
    <div class = "room-container pl-3 col-4 col-xl-3">
    <div class="room mt-2 col-offset-1">
        <h4 class = "text-muted">Room: </h4>
        <h5 class = 'display room-name'></h5>
        <h4 class = "text-muted">Chat Count: </h4>
        <h5 class = 'display chat-count'></h5>
        <h4 class = "text-muted">Username: </h4>
        <h5 class = 'display username'></h5>
    </div>
    <p class = "lead footer" id="me"> { } with <img class = "heart" src="../js/img/heart.svg"> by <a href="https://siwiec.us">Adam Siwiec</a></h3>
</div>

<div  class="right-status-container col-8 col-xl-9">
    <div id="avatar"></div>
    <div id="status-container">
        <h4 class = "pl-1 pt-1">Status: </h4>
        <div class = "pl-1" id = "status">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.row`'s, compensate for the guttering that gets applied to columns. From [Docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#how-it-works)

> Rows are horizontal groups of columns that ensure your columns are lined up properly. We use the negative margin method on `.row` to ensure all your content is aligned properly down the left side.

Try the following:

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/eLad8q10/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-xl-3 no-gutter">
    LEFT
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 col-xl-9">
     RIGHT
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work, but now for the .col-4, it has no padding just on the left side. What's up with that?

Comment: I fixed this by adding another div with class .container-fluid to wrap everything!