# Bootstrap 4 (Alpha 6) columns: col-x-n being ignored in table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Please see the following jsfiddle which illustrates an issue I have been having today

https://jsfiddle.net/juuxhbf7/

Anyone tell me why all the the `col-md-n`seem to be being ignored and the first column set superwide? From experimentation I can set ONE of the columns to take up most of the space (though not the proportion I asked for) ...

https://jsfiddle.net/s1tv8kby/

But try to set more than one, and it is only the first one that gets anything - again superwide.

https://jsfiddle.net/rdg1b6xw/

NOTE: I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517967/bootstrap-4-alpha-6-column-taking-up-full-width), but the solutions offered there do not seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the `.table` class in the table. Also, I'm not sure that using the `col-*` classes in the table is supported in BS 4 now that flexbox is the default for columns. You can use the `d-inline-block` class as a workaround.

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr class="whatever">
        <th>A</th>
        <th class="d-inline-block col-4">B</th>
        <th class="d-inline-block col-6">C</th>
        <th>D</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/yNvGobGjOC

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to do the trick!! But, every <th> must have a col width assigned, AND it has to also be applied to all the <td>s in the rows as well as the header. It does not play with "table-responsive" (which makes sense, as that makes a fully automatic layout based on the max data widths in each column). SO, what ARE we supposed to use these days for column distribution? (I don't mean just for "table", but also CSS tables).